# Mostrar check box de recyclerview en pdf - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Buen dia.

Estoy exportando mi recyclerview en PDF, mi reyclerview contiene una lista de preguntas y check box donde el usuario va marcando.

Con este codigo eh logrado exportar en PDF y todos los item.

Mi clase CrearArchivo.kt

```
  open  fun salvarPDF(bitmap: Bitmap, nombreDeArchivo : String): String?{
    archivo = File(pasta, "$nombreDeArchivo.pdf")

        val archivoPDF = PdfDocument()
        val pageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo = PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, 1).create()
        val pagina : PdfDocument.Page = archivoPDF.startPage(pageInfo)
        val canvas : Canvas = pagina.canvas

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null, Rect(0,0,bitmap.width, bitmap.height),null)
        archivoPDF.finishPage(pagina)

    try {
        archivo!!.createNewFile()
        val streamDeSalidad: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(archivo)
        archivoPDF.writeTo(streamDeSalidad)
        streamDeSalidad.close()
        archivoPDF.close()

    }catch (e: IOException){
        return "error en crear$e"
    }

    return "creado"

}
```

y en mi activity tengo el siguiente codigo el cual se encarga de recorrer el reyclerview y sus item.

```
fun getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(view: RecyclerView): Bitmap? {
    val adapter = view.adapter
    var bigBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    if (adapter != null) {
        val size = adapter.itemCount
        var height = 0
        val paint = Paint()
        var iHeight = 0
        val maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()
        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        val cacheSize = maxMemory / 8
        val bitmaCache =
            LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize)
        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val holder =
                adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i))
            adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i)
            holder.itemView.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    view.width,
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                ),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    0,
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
                )
            )
            holder.itemView.layout(
                0,
                0,
                holder.itemView.measuredWidth,
                holder.itemView.measuredHeight
            )
            holder.itemView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            holder.itemView.buildDrawingCache()
            val drawingCache = holder.itemView.drawingCache
            if (drawingCache != null) {
                bitmaCache.put(i.toString(), drawingCache)
            }
                       

    //holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
//                holder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
                height += holder.itemView.measuredHeight
            }
            bigBitmap =
                Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, height * size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val bigCanvas = Canvas(bigBitmap)
            bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
            for (i in 0 until size) {
                val bitmap = bitmaCache[i.toString()]
                bigCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap!!, 0f, iHeight.toFloat(), paint)
                iHeight += bitmap.height

                bitmap.recycle()
            }
        }
        return bigBitmap
    }
```

Con esto se exporta bien, pero el problema recae cuando el usuario marca alguna casilla de respuesta del checkbox en el formato PDF las casillas no se ve lo marcado solo se pinta los bordes mas no sale el ASPA de marcado.

Ejemplo :

Como verán no se visualiza el ASPA de lo marcado, solo se pinta los bordes.

En que parte estaré fallando en el código o si falta agregar algo mas.

Agradezco su apoyo.

[image: NO SE VISUALIZA EL ASPA DE LO MARCADO]

Comment: Ya que lo estás renderizado en una imagen, no crees que sería más fácil [dibujar el activity a un canvas/bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532061/13419694)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando un poco logre solucionar este caso, solo tenia que crear 1 archivo .xml llamado selector y aplicar el siguiente codigo.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_chbktrue2">

</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cvacio"></item>
```

Y llamarlo asi en mi estructura.xml

```
  <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chbksi2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
                    android:button="@drawable/selector"

                    android:text="@string/check_si" />
```

Ahora se visualiza de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]